# sqlite database lock after scp to school account

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a school java project that I am working on. It involves an sqlite database. I run an ant build script on my machine (Mac OS X) to import some data into the sqlite file. It works fine on my machine. I then compress my project folder to a zip file and scp the zip to my university's student CS account. The university's server is like a round-robin that drops my ssh session (scp) onto one of the labs' free machines (linux). I then ssh into my account, unzip the file, and try to run the ant script. It starts off ok, but after about the 5th sql command to create a table it complains that my sqlite database file is locked.

I've heard that NFS fileshares are a bit buggy with sqlite...but does the university's server match that description? I've combed my code and make sure that I close all prepared statements and database transactions appropriately.

Does this sound like a problem on my end? the university's end? platform dependence? I've been at this for hours trying to figure it out...

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT: I'll include some code to clarify:**

This works fine on my Mac. I zip my project, scp to student account, unzip it there, and run it. See below the code for the thrown sql exception that the database is locked. The project is single-threaded. No other part of the program is using this database.

```
    //commands to drop tables, then create them
    List<String> sqls = db.getDBCreationCommands();  
    Statement stmt = null;
    db.startTransaction();  //gets connection, sets autocommit(false)

    try {
        stmt = db.getConnection().createStatement();

        for(String sql : sqls){
            stmt.addBatch(sql);
        }
        stmt.executeBatch();  //gets through a couple of entries just fine, then quits
        db.endTransaction(true); //commits and closes connection
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        db.endTransaction(false); //roll back and close connection
        System.out.println("ERROR COULD NOT DROP DATABASE");
        throw new ServerException(e);
    }
    finally{
        if(stmt != null)
            try {
                stmt.close();
            }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here's the exception:

```
[java] DROPPING DATABASE . . . . . . . . .ERROR COULD NOT DROP DATABASEException in thread "main" server.ServerException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 5: database is locked
 [java] 
 [java]     at server.database.MasterAccess.resetDatabase(MasterAccess.java:56)
 [java]     at xml.parsing.DataImporter.main(DataImporter.java:39)
 [java] Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 5: database is locked
 [java]     at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeBatch(Stmt.java:168)
 [java]     at server.database.MasterAccess.resetDatabase(MasterAccess.java:47)
 [java]     ... 1 more
```

The sql commands are not anything special...just a few drop tables and then create tables commands.

My suspicion is that the server that manages my 'home folder' at school is trying to sync my network home folder with the linux machine I'm currently ssh'd in to. That would be copying the sqlite file at the same time as i'm trying to run it? Does that sound like a possibility?

**EDIT**
I installed virtualbox and linux on my mac, copied over the files, and am running in to the same problem as the linux machines at school. Could this be something to do with platform dependence?

Comment: You should provide more details in what exactly is happening. As currently stated, it is impossible to answer this question without having mind reading powers

Comment: @mvp you're right. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it for another few hours and changed my sql commands from `create table TABLENAME...` to `create table if not exists TABLENAME`. I don't know if it has anything to do with the db transaction, but it didn't like the plain old `create table`. Seemed to work, but we'll really see when I pass off the project. I still have no idea why my mac didn't complain, yet linux did.